Using generating functions prove that $\sum_{k=r}^{2n-1} k2^k \binom{2n-k-1}{n-1} = n2^r \binom{2n-r}{n}$
Inspired by the question: How to prove? $\sum_{k=r}^{2n-1}k2^k{2n-k-1\choose n-1}=n2^r{2n-r\choose n}$.
Using generating functions prove that
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{k=r}^{2n-1} k2^k \binom{2n-k-1}{n-1} = n2^r \binom{2n-r}{n}
\end{equation*}
First, let summation run over $k$ in range $k=0$ to $k=2n-1-r$
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1-r} (r+k) 2^{r+k} \binom{2n-(r+k)-1}{n-1}
\end{align*}
So it is clear that we are looking for the coefficient of $z^{2n-1-r}$ in multiplication of certain generating functions.
Another point worth attention is the lower index $n-1$ of the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n-(r+k)-1}{n-1}$,
it is tricky because it hides another independent variable.
Let $j=n-1$, then
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1-r} (r+k) 2^{r+k} \binom{2n-(r+k)-1}{j}
\end{align*}
Let be $t=2n-1-r$, then
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{t} (r+k) 2^{r+k} \binom{t-k}{j}
\end{align*}
The term $(r+k)$ can be replaced by binomial coefficient $\binom{r+k}{1}$, then
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{t} 2^{r+k} \binom{r+k}{1} \binom{t-k}{j}
\end{align*}
Moving $2r$ out of summation yields
\begin{align*}
    2^r \sum_{k=0}^{t} 2^{k} \binom{r+k}{1} \binom{t-k}{j}
\end{align*}
Therefore, using generating functions for binomial coefficients
\begin{align*}
    \binom{r+k}{1} &= [z^{r+k}] (1+z)^1 \\
    \binom{t-k}{j} &= [z^{t-k}] (1+z)^j
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
    \binom{r+k}{1} \binom{t-k}{j} &= [z^{r+k}] (1+z)^1 \cdot [z^{t-k}] (1+z)^j \\
    &= [z^{r+t}] (1+z)^{j+1} = \binom{r+t}{j+1}
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
    2^r \sum_{k=0}^{t} 2^{k} \binom{r+k}{1} \binom{t-k}{j} &= 2^r \binom{r+t}{j+1} \sum_{k=0}^{t} 2^{k} \\
    &= 2^r \binom{r+t}{j+1} (2^{t+1} - 1) \\
    &= \binom{r+t}{j+1} (2^{r+t+1} - 2^r)
\end{align*}
Taking $j=n-1$ and $t=2n-1-r$ yields
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^{2n-1-r} (r+k) 2^{r+k} \binom{2n-(r+k)-1}{j} &= \sum_{k=r}^{2n-1} k2^k \binom{2n-k-1}{n-1} \\
    &= \binom{2n-1}{n} (2^{2n} - 2^r)
\end{align*}
Which is different closed form than the one given in the problem.
Point out on the mistake in current solution and propose a correct one.
Edit (10/09/2024): Formulae corrected according to @RobPratt comment

In the first step, changing the index in $\sum_{k=r}^{2n-1} a_k$ should yield $\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1-r} a_{r+k}$, whereas you have $\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} a_{r+k}$.
